# Extract HTML content from a webpage using java

Tags: java, html

I am trying to extract HTML content of a webpage using JAVA. But the problem is the page which I am trying to load, keeps expanding if the user scrolls down. So my code is able to extract only whatever the page loads at first time. How do i extract the remaining part of the HTML code which is generated usually when the user scrolls down.

Comment: Can you post the URL you're trying to hit? It's probably a matter of understanding what parameters to pass to an AJAX call.

Comment: @orangepips I am trying to get the contents of 9gag.com. Just experimental for learning :)

Answer (score 3):

Open up firebug or chrome developer tools.  Look at the network tab. When you scroll down an ajax call will be made.  Note this url and the params.  YOu will manually have to make the call to the appropriate url (the ajax url) and parse the response which may or may not be html.

Comment: Yes I found that, thanks :) But the problem I found is this site, keeps updating those links too :(

Comment: Sorry I misunderstood